# Managed Package Permission Set missing permissions

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets

I've created a permission set and included it in a 2nd generation managed package. However, when I install or upgrade the package some of the permissions I've assigned remain unchecked. These include:

- Object Settings > Contacts > Read
- Object Settings > Contacts > Email > Read Access
- System Permissions > API Enabled

I've also given the same permission set full access to a bunch of custom objects which are being added correctly.

When I push to a scratch Org the permissions are all enabled and I can see the settings in the permission set metadata.

Any ideas why these 3 permissions aren't being included when packaged?

Comment: Hello Jonny, is this a 2nd package or first?

Comment: 2nd generation. I'll add to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot package those types of permissions. See [About Permission Sets and Profile Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm) in the ISVforce Guide:

> Do they include standard object permissions?  No

> Do they include user permissions? No.

In general you cannot package changes that have impact on access outside the scope of your application.

Comment: Sounds fair but David, is not it "API Enabled" considered "System Permissions"? Maybe that is under the same bucket but it made me wonder.

Comment: Worth noting that unlocked packages don't appear to suffer the same "restrictions" with packaged permission sets.